# CakePHP: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in view

Tags: cakephp, model, view, notice

I am dealing with a wierd problem.
I have the `Config` model, together with these associations:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Language' => array(
        'className' => 'Language',
        'foreignKey' => 'default_language',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Webmaster' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'webmaster',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'default_group',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
```

In my `ConfigsController` I have the `edit()` action:

```
function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid config', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Config->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The config has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The config could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Config->read(null, $id);
    }
    $languages = $this->Config->Language->find('list');
    $webmasters = $this->Config->Webmaster->find('list');
    $groups = $this->Config->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('languages', 'groups', 'webmasters'));
}
```

And in my `edit.ctp` view, I have:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Language');
echo $this->Form->input('Webmaster');
echo $this->Form->input('Group');
```

Now, here is the problem: The group is correctly selected, but the other two (webmaster and language) are reseted on the first option, have **no** `selected` attribute, and as a "bonus", the language select displays this error: `Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset: 0 [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 859]`

I struggled for almost 2 hours and couldn't find the isuue for this wierd problem. Could you please help me? Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is what the debugger shows:

```
Helper::__selectedArray() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 859
```

Helper::value() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 712
Helper::_initInputField() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 753
FormHelper::_initInputField() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/form.php, line 2182
FormHelper::select() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/form.php, line 1438
FormHelper::input() - CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/form.php, line 882
include - APP/views/configs/edit.ctp, line 10
View::_render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 723
View::render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 419
Controller::render() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 913
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 207
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83

And in the 'code' tab:

```
 if (!empty($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $var) {
            $array[$var[$key]] = $var[$key];
```

Comment: Give us the stack trace of your error. (Click on "Notice (8)" to open it up > Then click on "Code") That might even help you find the solution.

Comment: I have edited the question. I tried to figure out what is the problem from what the debugger was showing, but I couldn't.

Comment: Could you show us line 10 of configs/edit.ctp?

Comment: Before I changed to the solution you gave, I had `echo $this->Form->input('Language');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code in your view instead:

```
echo $this->Form->input('default_language', array('options' => $languages));
echo $this->Form->input('webmaster', array('options' => $webmasters));
echo $this->Form->input('default_group', array('options' => $groups));
```

This would create a "select" drop down for each, and associate them correctly with the relevant fields.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! But still, do you have any idea why it worked only "half" with the code I had? It seems very odd to me.